# Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl's token validity

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have a question regarding the "token" in the url(&token=) when using getDownloadUrl of FirebaseStorage.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/someapplication.appspot.com/o/images%2Fsample.png?alt=media&token=123456

From docs, it says that it returns a "long lived" download url
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL

Problem is, im saving the downloadUrl in FirebaseDatabase like

```
-chatroom
  - c1
    - m1
      -message: "Sent a photo"
      -photoUrl: downloadUrl here
```

From what i understand it is not a lifetime token so at some point in time the token will not be valid. So when I display this url in an ImageView for example, it will not load the image.

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(downloadUrl)
  .into(imageView)
```

I do understand I can use something like this in firebase to generate a new one.

```
StorageReference sr = getReferenceFromUrl(downloadUrl)
//pseudo-code
sr.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener((Uri newUri) => {
  Picasso.with(context)
  .load(newUri)
  .into(imageView)
});
```

BUT! this process has an overhead of always getting a new download url in the process.

So again, how long will the token lived? Also if it is not a lifetime token, how should we store the download url properly?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Firebase Storage tokens do not expire.**

They may be revoked from the Firebase Console, which would invalidate URLs based on them.

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find documentation that says this? I couldn't find any. [The official docs for downloading images](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) doesn't say anything, which I guess is good news.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. I used the download URL from the firebase storage web API that is provided in the task returned from `put()`. (Documentation is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files under Monitor Upload Progress). There's no mention of expiration, but now after a few months my download link resolves to this XML: `<Error><Code>ExpiredToken</Code><Message>The provided token has expired.</Message><Details>Request has expired: 1511581939</Details></Error>`

Comment: That most likely means your token was revoked.

Comment: Okay now i am confused. @FrankvanPuffelen , can a downloadURL expire without me revoking the token from the console? matth's situation is very scary if it is true.

Comment: See this answer (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/244#issuecomment-405661688) from the guy who built firebase storage