# Firebase Storage URL format instead of using References

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I wanted to know how long lived the firebase storage URL's are.
I'm using firebase storage to host some static images. Currently using the file references to get the url's in app.
But would like to skip this step and just use the URL's instead. Does anyone know what if anything will cause first part of the URL to change?
(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/)

**Total URL**
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{Project_ID}.appspot.com/o/{FILE_PATH}?alt=media&token={TOKEN}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the URL (`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/`) will only change if the Firebase Storage API ever changes. Since this hasn't happened since its release in May 2016, and isn't planned to happen at any point at the moment, we can be certain it is a really infrequent occurrence.

The `{Project_ID}.appspot.com/o/` will only change if you have a different project. For an existing project this will never change.

The `{FILE_PATH}` is the path to your file, so will only be different when referring to a different file.

And `token={TOKEN}` will only stop working if you revoke the token, as answer here: [Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl's token validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593002/firebase-storage-getdownloadurls-token-validity)

Answer (score 1):

A download URL will last forever, or until its specific token is rejected from the Firebase console.